# A Java library for language-independent source code analysis

Tags: library, java, code-analysis, modeling, compiler

I'm looking for a Java library that would allow for modeling the elements of the source of an OOP programming language and performing post-parse semantic analysis on them.

This library might have classes like "Class", "DataMember", "Method", "Type", "Instruction", etc.

Many compilers implement their own semantic model, despite closely-related languages having similar semantic models that are easy to abstract into a generic one covering those related cases.

I'm planning to use this to toy around by implementing transcompilers.

Comment: I think you'll find that trying to abstract away the differences between languages, will give you a program representation with sloppy semantics.  And then you *can't* "transpile" it right.    A class in Java seems a lot like one in JavaScript, but "inheritance" works completely differently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Polyglot](https://github.com/polyglot-compiler/polyglot).

The API is particularly anti-ergonomic, ugly and against pretty much each one of modern Java conventions I know. But it seems to do the job.